# Haskell-pipes: how to use drawAll to test a producer with a MonadSafe constraint?

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes, haskell-pipes-safe

I have a producer which, given a path, traverses the filesystem yielding Haskell files' paths. It's built on top of pipes-files:

```
import Pipes
import Pipes.Files
import Pipes.Safe
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Data.List (isSuffixOf)
import System.Directory (doesFileExist)


-- | Starting from a path, generate a sequence of paths corresponding
--   to Haskell files. The fileystem is traversed depth-first.
allFiles :: (MonadIO m, MonadSafe m) => FilePath -> IO (Producer FilePath m ())
allFiles path = do
    isFile <- doesFileExist path
    if isFile then return $ each [path] >-> P.filter (".hs" `isSuffixOf`)
              else return $ find path (glob "*.hs" <> regular)
```

Now I'd like to test it with Hspec, but I'm finding it hard to transform the producer into a list. It would be simpler, were it not for that `MonadSafe m` constraint which causes a lot of type errors. Here is what I wrote:

```
import Pipes
import Pipes.Safe
import Pipes.Parse
import Test.Hspec


shouldReturnP :: (MonadIO m, MonadSafe m)
              => IO (Producer FilePath m ()) -> [FilePath] -> Expectation
shouldReturnP action res = do
    prod <- action
    let paths = runSafeT $ evalStateT drawAll prod
    paths `shouldBe` res
```

This is how it should be used:

```
spec :: Spec
spec = do
    describe "allFiles" $
        it "traverses the filesystem depth-first returning only hs files" $
            allFiles ("test" </> "tree") `shouldReturnP`
                [ "test" </> "tree" </> "a.hs"
                , "test" </> "tree" </> "sub"  </> "b.hs"
                , "test" </> "tree" </> "sub"  </> "c.hs"
                , "test" </> "tree" </> "sub2" </> "a.hs"
                , "test" </> "tree" </> "sub2" </> "e.hs"
                ]
```

Compiling the tests gives the following errors:

```
test/Spec.hs:57:47:
    Couldn't match type ‘m’ with ‘Pipes.Safe.SafeT []’
      ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            shouldReturnP :: (MonadIO m, MonadSafe m) =>
                             IO (Producer FilePath m ()) -> [FilePath] -> Expectation
          at test/Spec.hs:53:18
    Expected type: Producer FilePath (Pipes.Safe.SafeT []) ()
      Actual type: Producer FilePath m ()
    Relevant bindings include
      prod :: Producer FilePath m () (bound at test/Spec.hs:56:5)
      action :: IO (Producer FilePath m ())
        (bound at test/Spec.hs:55:15)
      shouldReturnP :: IO (Producer FilePath m ())
                       -> [FilePath] -> Expectation
        (bound at test/Spec.hs:55:1)
    In the second argument of ‘evalStateT’, namely ‘prod’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘evalStateT drawAll prod’

test/Spec.hs:58:22:
    Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: [[FilePath]]
      Actual type: [FilePath]
    In the second argument of ‘shouldBe’, namely ‘res’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: paths  res
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `toListM` from Pipes.Prelude:

```
...
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
...

files1 :: (MonadIO m, MonadSafe m) => Producer FilePath m ()
files1 = find "." (glob "*.hs" <> regular)

test1 = do
  got <- runSafeT $ runEffect $ P.toListM files1
  shouldBe got ["a.hs", "b.hs", "c.hs"]

-- using `allFiles`:

test2 = do
  prod <- allFiles "."
  got <- runSafeT $ runEffect $ P.toListM prod
  shouldBe got ["a.hs", "b.hs"]
```

To write your `shouldReturnP` function, start with this:

```
shouldReturnP1 prod expected = do
  let _ = expected :: [FilePath]
  got <- runSafeT $ P.toListM prod
  shouldBe got expected
```

and have ghc tell you what the type is, which is:

```
shouldReturnP1
  :: (Eq a, Show a) => Producer a (SafeT IO) () -> [a] -> IO ()
```

You can test it with:

```
testP1 = shouldReturnP1 files1 ["a.hs", "b.hs", "c.hs"]
```

For the IO-action version, write:

```
shouldReturnP2 action expected = do
  let _ = expected :: [FilePath]
  prod <- action
  paths <- runSafeT $ runEffect $ P.toListM prod
  paths `shouldBe` expected
```

and ghc tells you the type is:

```
shouldReturnP2
  :: IO (Producer FilePath (SafeT IO) ()) -> [FilePath] -> IO ()
```

and a test:

```
testP2 = shouldReturnP2 (allfiles ".") ["a1.hs"]
```

**Update**

Per the discussion in the comments about putting the `doesFileExist` check in the pipe:

```
allfiles2 :: MonadSafe m => FilePath -> Producer FilePath m ()
allfiles2 path = do
  exists <- liftIO $ doesFileExist path
  if exists
    then each [path] >-> P.filter (".hs" `isSuffixOf`)
    else find path (glob "*.hs" <> regular)
```

Comment: I don't think the `runEffect` is required, because `toListM` already returns a list, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Somehow I had overlooked `toListM` from the Prelude. And yes, I had to change the type signature of `shouldReturnP` to `shouldReturnP :: IO (Producer FilePath (SafeT IO) ()) -> [FilePath] -> Expectation` because the constraint `(MonadIO m, MonadSafe m)` wasn't enough. Nice trick with the wildcard there.

Comment: You're right - the runEffect isn't necessary - answer updated.

Comment: Btw - I'm thinking it would be cleaner if `allfiles` did the existence test within the pipe so that `allfiles path` was a Producer instead of an IO (Producer ...).

Comment: That would indeed be neater, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. It would mean to fork the pipeline. I'll think about it.

Comment: I've appended to the answer.

Comment: Ah I keep forgetting about `liftiO` which really makes things simpler and easier to read. Thanks a lot.